# SQL Query: Get rows (all columns) from table basied on one distinct column

Tags: sql, distinct

this is a sample data to explain my case:

[image]

I want to get data **distinct by EMPLOYID**, so only *5199, 6000, 6100* employees returned, and for the rest of columns what ever data returned it would be OK

**My try:**
I planned to get distinct EMPLOYID first then get top 1 for each Employee but it seems need a loop, and in my case i restricted to only select query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2005 or later, here's a basic example to demonstrate one approach:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (ID INTEGER, NameField VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @Data VALUES (1, 'A')
INSERT @Data VALUES (1, 'B')
INSERT @Data VALUES (1, 'C')
INSERT @Data VALUES (2, 'A')
INSERT @Data VALUES (3, 'C')
INSERT @Data VALUES (3, 'B')

SELECT ID, NameField FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS RowNo, *
FROM @Data
) x
WHERE RowNo = 1
```

Here's the reference on [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try `SELECT * FROM myTable GROUP BY EMPLOYID`

Comment: this wont work, as with GROUP BY you can only SELECT the columns in the group by expression

Comment: I think I should be banned from answering SQL-related questions... at least when I'm not at a computer I can test them on :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but I think this should do the trick:

```
declare @DISTINCTEMPLOYIDS table
    (IDS  char(8)) --whatever datatype employid is

insert into @DISTINCTEMPLOYIDS (IDS)
select distinct EMPLOYID
from TABLENAME

select *
from TABLENAME as t
join @@DISTINCTEMPLOYIDS as d
on t.EMPLOYID = d.EMPLOYID
```

Remember to change TABLENAME to whatever the name of your table is